# How do you form a raid group in Firefall?

Tags: firefall

I'm interested in forming a raid with a handful of friends (more than 5) to do various fun things. I can't seem to find what commands, etc. are required to form a raid group (6 or more players). How does one accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to form a platoon you have 2 options.

1. Invite a 6th member to your squad, the game will ask you to upgrade it to a platoon.
2. Click on your name (if you are the squad lead) and on the context menu will be the option to change the squad into a platoon.

A couple things to note. Platoons work differently than squads. XP Rewards are **not** shared, thumpers are not shared, and jobs are not shared. You also can't enter instance missions with platoons.

Platoons (currently) are meant for raids and Broken Peninsula(PvP) only.